# Second chern class and length of a zero dimensional sheaf on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let, $\mathcal T$ be a $0$ dimensional sheaf on a $K3$ surface.

Then is it true that $c_2(\mathcal T) = - h^0(\mathcal T)$?

If we consider $Z =Supp(\mathcal T)$,then $Z$ is a zero dimensional subscheme and we know that $c_2(\mathcal I_Z) = h^0(\mathcal O_Z)$. Can the desired relation be deduced from here?

Any help from anyone is  welcome.

Comment: The formula is correct. To deduce first consider the case of the structure sheaf of a point (can apply Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch here), then filter $T$ by such sheaves.